# xbox controller keys wont map properly

Tags: games, steam

I am using a wired x box 360 afterglow controller. I plugged it in and installed xboxdrv. On the joystick pane all the buttons are mapped properly but when I load a game on steam several of the buttons don't work and the ones that do work are not mapped to what they actually are (right trigger is the start button etc..) i went into the steam controller setting and remapped everything there to the proper place. When I load up a game afterwards its the same thing. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and cannot seem to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the package `ubuntu-xboxdrv` from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rael-gc/+archive/ubuntu-xboxdrv):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
```

This package provides additional configurations over the stock `xboxdrv`, creating a service for it and a "Joysticks" entry on System Panel.

The shoulder buttons are mapped as buttons (not triggers), but you can see how to change some configurations in the [package repo](https://github.com/raelgc/ubuntu_xboxdrv).

Comment: ok that worked to make the A, B, Y, A buttons map properly. However i am not sure how i edit the triggers to stop being the start and select buttons. the link you gave shows how but i do not know how to edit the file it is talking about. Is there more newbie type instructions on how to do this? thank you for your response and time.

Comment: It just doesn't tell you what text editor to invoke in Terminal to make the changes. I like `pico` for its simplicity; try `sudo pico /etc/default/xboxdrv`

Comment: how do i save the changes?

Comment: `ctrl+o` to save, `ctrl+x` to exit.

Comment: well that all worked any now some games seem to work fine while others still perfer to use the triggers as start buttons and the A button as the B button. I think i give up =/

Comment: Mike, try change the config `MIMIC_XPAD` to `false`.